# Authentication Flow used in a Blazor Web Assembly App (standalone)

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Reading the microsoft documentation does not give a clear idea of which Authentication flow is used in a Blazor WebAssembly App.

I am creating a Blazor web App that is authenticating against Azure AD. I understand I have to use MSAL library for it. The package used for Blazor WebAssembly is Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal. But could not find a documentation explaining what auth flow this library use?

Could someone please point to the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an example with OpenId Connect and Google Authentication you can check my [repo](https://github.com/ylr-research/BlazorWASMAuthOIDC).

Answer (score 0):

I used this section to get MSAL up and running
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0